# How to map lots of data points on one plot? when grouping by shape is not applicable

Tags: r, plot, colors, ggplot2, shapes

I'm trying to plot two metrics' scores from 50 simulations. I need to map each simulation on the plot but shape accepts only 8, and using color for 50 groups doesn't seem to look good on plot at all(I tried and it was terrible!) Any suggestions?

```
 myplot<- ggplot(new, aes(sppp_loss, history)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = metric),
         position = position_jitter(width = 0.3, height = 0)) + 
 geom_smooth (aes(x=sppp_loss , y= history, color=metric, group=(metric)), method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

Subset of data

```
   metric   history    sppp_loss      sim
   ED_loss  1.209177471 5            tree1
   ED_loss  1.453112762 5            tree2
   ED_loss  1.174947503 5            tree3
   ED_loss  1.226344648 5            tree4
   ED_loss  0.972865697 5            tree5
```

cheers

Comment: You have to differentiate 50 data sources? Using one plot just doesn't seem reasonable no matter whether you are using colour, shape, size etc. Plot multiple plots as facets or reduce the dimensions of your data would be my only two suggestions.

Comment: is there any way to include text on the plot, like tree1, tree2 etc?

Comment: You could use the value of `sim` as the actual point markers, but it will be very cluttered with 50 different values. At the least you'll want to shorten it to `t1`, `t2`, etc. (or even just the number alone), but faceting is a better option. Anyway, here's a conceptual example using a built-in data set: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=carb), position=position_jitter(width=0.2,height=0))`

Comment: Thanks @eipi10, this would be good enough for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment solved your problem, I'm converting it to an answer:

You could use the value of sim as the actual point markers, but it will be very cluttered with 50 different values. At the least you'll want to shorten it to t1, t2, etc. (or even just the number alone), but faceting is a better option (as noted by @thelatemail). Anyway, here's a conceptual example using a built-in data set:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) + 
     geom_text(aes(label=carb), position=position_jitter(width=0.2,height=0))
```